What more can be done to get rid of illegal content in Discussions?
Despite the calls for something to be done, nothing is being done. At the time of writing there is a post advertising prostitution in the Discussions section of the site and it's been there for over 2 hours. This is not okay. This is not the fault of the moderators or curators, this is squarely with Stack Overflow and the lack of tooling for moderators, lack of restrictions for new users and lack of guidance for users about the feature.
Seeing spam is one thing, but an advertisement left in situ for this length of time for that type of service is a disgrace. I've also seen posts for drugs and other illegal services.
Apart from flagging as spam, what can a "normal" user like myself do to get such content destroyed quickly, considering that Stack Overflow themselves have no interest in fixing the problem.

"Apart from flagging as spam..." I mean, that's exactly what you're supposed to do. That's all you or any other normal user is ever expected to do. So this question makes little sense. Unless the answer is to block Discussions so you never see the trash pile. If the company doesn't want to make it better, that's their choice, isn't it? What would you possibly expect anyone else to do about it? Would we even want users to be able to do anything else about it? (I mean, you could spin up more accounts, gain some rep on each, and then raise multiple spam flags, but that's abuse.)

The problem, @Cody , is we both know that those flags are entirely separate to mod flags for the main site, and mods can only check Discussion flags by activitely checking Discussions, which there is no incentive for you to do. If Spam flags worked, then it wouldn't take over 2 hours to remove illegal content.

Yes, that's all 100% true. I agree that Discussions was only half-implemented and has no effective moderation tools. I further agree that the company doesn't seem to care about this, because they've been told about since the very beginning, yet the problem keeps getting worse with absolutely no attention paid to it. But your question is not phrased as a bug report on Discussions. You're asking a very concrete question in your last paragraph, which is all that I was addressing in my comment. I don't think I want normal users to be able to do anything on spam other than flagging it.

I came across this meta answer and tried to trace back the ToS but I cannot locate the relevant segment of illegal content. I also see this MSE post. From my understanding, StackExchange does not care about illegal content on the site, at least now.

@ray spam is not tolerated, though.

If th answer is "nothing" then that is an answer, @Cody . I'd probably downvote such an answer as well as accept it, because as much as i don't agree with that being the solution, doesn't mean it's not.

When we say "illegal" here, which jurisdiction is relevant?

What you can do is very simple: stop curating, stop flagging, stop doing free cleanup work for SE. When the garbage is piled higher and higher and discussions looks like an unprotected guestbook on some abandoned web1.0 site, SE will probably be compelled to act.

The rules of responsibilities of a publisher haven't changed with the dawn of Internet. If there is an SO post advertising illegal content, then SO is legally responsible. Simply call the police and they will take it from there.

At this point, just forget about them. We're due another update on discussions where feedback will be given and filed next to all the other feedback. But at least they're thankful

For now, we can do little. If you're an EU citizen, you can petition your EU reps to have Stack Exchange recognized as a large online platform under the digital services act, and then they'd have a substantial liability associated with failing to moderate illegal content.

Or just nuke discussions from orbit.

Without an API (needed for the automated community tooling made by Charcoal to work), there's no way to have spam handling in Discussions be up to par with the rest of the network. It's just not possible.
Though you can't use the tools, the people from Charcoal can help. Posting a message in Charcoal HQ gives the problem greater visibility, so other people can help flagging. That's sometimes how I see there's spam in Discussions. Additionally, they can use the information to make sure the user and their spam message will be quickly caught if it's reposted elsewhere on the network.
Another option is to get another Discussion moderator or two who will be active when this spam is happening. For me at least, I check Discussion flags in the morning (more or less this time) and often see a number of spam flags on Discussions posted while I was asleep. (The workload otherwise for Discussions is under control.)

"Posting a message in Charcoal HQ gives the problem greater visibility" Why not take it to SOCVR or anywhere else? Charcoal is getting sick and tired of the lack of support for discussions, many users won't engage on Discussions until SE finally adds API support.

@Mast as one of the more frequent reporters of Discussions related things in Charcoal - I do it because SOCVR wasn't sold on the idea at the time I started doing it.

@Mast There may be other chats that would accept these requests, but I'm only familiar with CHQ. Feel free to give suggestions for chats you're familiar with.

@VLAZ CHQ isn't sold on the idea either.

A simple way would be to bring in a minimum reputation requirement. Even a minimum of 2 reputation means a spammer can't spin up a new account and post spam on a basically undermoderated site. Considering some spammers seem to ramp up activity based on the level of moderation there is, it might be worth considering the aftermath of a proper large scale spam attack like the one on webapps some time back.
You can always adjust reputation levels afterwards when better mechanisms are in place.

Minimum reputation has been suggested multiple times, including twice by myself; once during the huge spam wave, and again as a proper proposal. They don't plan to increase it, even though it will certainly solve many of the issues with the area of the site.

Might be worth re-iterating till someone consider it then, or things go horribly wrong then

I was already doing so in the post I was writing as you replied here.

Just set the minimum to whatever minimum there is to be able to use chat. Keep it simple... and consistent.
